# Создание дерева процессов

Tags: c

Я стараюсь создать дерево процессов как на первом скриншоте. Мой код работает не совсем правильно. Результат работы моего кода показан на втором скриншоте Проблема в том, что я не знаю как создать последнее поколение процессов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main() {
    int i;
    int j;

    pid_t ppid;
    pid_t cpid;
    ppid = getpid();
    printf("I'm the parent, my PID is: %d\n", ppid);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ppid = fork();
    if (ppid == 0) {
         printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
             for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
             ppid = fork();
         if (ppid == 0) {
             printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
             sleep(60);
             printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
             exit(0);
         }
         }
         sleep(60);
         printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
         exit(0);
    }   
    }


    sleep(1);
    printf("I'm process %d. Waiting for one of my children to complete", getpid());
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Eltern: I'm done\n");
    printf("... and bye. \n");
}
```

Comment: Вы понимаете как работает `fork()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вам нужно добавить третье поколение потоков просто. Для каждого потока из второго поколения (которых в цикле создается два) вам внутри нужно еще раз вызвать fork. Там где результат fork==0 вствавить код для потока с последнего уровня, в ином случае - поместить код потока втрого уровня.

```
       for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            ppid = fork();
            if (ppid == 0) {
                //child 1..2
                ppid=fork();
                if (ppid==0) {
                    // child 1..1 потоки с последнего 3 уровня выполнят этот код
                    printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
                    sleep(60);
                    printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
                    exit(0);
                } else {
                    // а этот код выполнят потоки втрого уровня
                    printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    sleep(60);
                    printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
                    exit(0);
                }       
            }
        }
```

Comment: Можно еще попутный вопрос? Как заставить каждый родительский процесс ждать окончания всех дочерних процессов? wait(null) ждет окончания любого дочернего, но не всех.

Comment: Поиск подсказывает, что можно вызывать wait(null) не один раз, а, например в цикле, пока резульатом не будет ECHILD, например так:        while ((wait(NULL)!=ECHILD) {sleep (1)}; Найдено здесь[https://stackoverflow.com/a/23872806/5521474]